# glmer with binary dependent variable: assumptions and model convergence

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, binary-data

I am new to generalized linear mixed models, and I am currently analyzing the effect of various fixed effects (three main and their two-way interactions) on a binary variable (0=behaviour absent, 1=behaviour present). I measured this variable repeatedly on the same individuals, and the distribution is skewed to 0 (behaviour rarely present).

I am not sure about the right distribution family. I chose `binomial`. I do not know what assumptions I should check and how in R? 
The largest model looks like this:

```
glmer(binary response ~ main 1 + main 2 + main 3 + interaction1-2 + interaction 2-3 + interaction 1-3 + (1|individualID), family=binomial)
```

I tried running the model using `glmer` from the lme4 package. I obtain results that correspond to what I expected from plots, but when I include interactions, I get this warning message:

```
Warning message:
In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.698727 (tol = 0.001, component 1)
```

Any idea why? Note that I do not get this message when interaction terms are removed from the model.
Unfortunately I am not allowed to share my dataset yet, so hopefully that is enough information to answer some of my questions.

Answer (score 1):

You should better fit the model using the adaptive Gaussian quadrature method rather than the Laplace approximation (i.e., set argument `nAGQ` of `glmer()` to a number higher than 1, e.g., 11 or 15).

Also, you could check the following link on [troubleshooting convergence problems with package **lme4**](https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/33653_57fc7b8e5d484c909b615d8633c01d51.html).

You could also give a try in the recent package [**GLMMadaptive**](https://drizopoulos.github.io/GLMMadaptive/) that uses by default the adaptive Gaussian quadrature, even if when you include random slopes in your model.